# Adding libraries with resources for android give dozen of "has already been defined" errors

Tags: android, eclipse

I am very new to android development with eclipse, and I encounter dozen of errors and problems. Here is the next one:

I am following the tutorial given [here](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html). I was about to enter the session [Setting Up the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html) , and to follow the instructions for 'Support Android 2.1 and Above', as I believe my phone has an android version below 3. Therefore, I followed the instructions given [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html), in the sub section 'Adding libraries with resources'. I successfully followed all steps, but after the last step for 'Add the library to your application project' (step 5) a red exclamation mark popped up at my project, and the console was filled with many error messages (listed below).

What have I done wrong this time? Maybe I tried to add something twice? How to revert my actions then? Or is the tutorial (again) incorrect?

Output of console (partial):

```
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:530: error: Attribute "searchViewGoIcon" has already been defined
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:532: error: Attribute "searchViewSearchIcon" has already been defined
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:534: error: Attribute "searchViewVoiceIcon" has already been defined
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:536: error: Attribute "searchViewEditQuery" has already been defined
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:538: error: Attribute "searchViewEditQueryBackground" has already been defined
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:540: error: Attribute "searchViewTextField" has already been defined
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:542: error: Attribute "searchViewTextFieldRight" has already been defined
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:544: error: Attribute "searchResultListItemHeight" has already been defined
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:546: error: Attribute "textAppearanceSearchResultTitle" has already been defined
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:548: error: Attribute "textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle" has already been defined
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:550: error: Attribute "textColorSearchUrl" has already been defined
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:552: error: Attribute "searchViewAutoCompleteTextView" has already been defined
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:557: error: Attribute "initialActivityCount" has already been defined
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:564: error: Attribute "expandActivityOverflowButtonDrawable" has already been defined
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:568: error: Attribute "activityChooserViewStyle" has already been defined
[2014-07-17 20:45:00 - TestApp] /home/alexander/Projects/Eclipse/appcompat_v7/res/values/attrs.xml:572: error: Attribute "textAllCaps" has already been defined
```

Addendum: Android Properties for my TestApp:

[image]

Maybe I am using this stupid appcompat_v7 twice? Should I remove one of them? If so, which? The `android-support-v7` has been added by the steps as explained above.

Comment: @Dyrborg: The code is fine, I did not change anything in the code. I wish I finally could start coding, and leave all of this installation crap alone. I am absolutely, 100% sure, the error came because of the steps I followed as explained in my question.

Comment: you are referencing the same library, if you just want to use `AppCompat` then remove reference to the first library that also contains `AppCompat`

Comment: I removed the second entry ('appcompat_v7'), but I still cannot run the project, the red exclamation mark at the project name stays.

Comment: I said remove the first one not the second one

Comment: I see. Maybe I fixed it. The exclamation mark has vanished. No idea, what I have done, or what AppCompat means... Thanks.

Comment: For future reference - look in the Problems view to see all your problems including project errors (Window > Show View > Problems)

Comment: Do you, by change, know of an eclipse tutorial? All those views, paths, perspectives, console, log-cat, problems etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove android-support-v7 library. I don't know why reason this second library appear sometimes. But you remove this and is solved.