# Trying to run a project in eclipse ADT, but keep on getting a huge list of xml errors

Tags: android, google-play-services

I imported an Android project into my eclipse workspace, but I get getting the following errors. I have googled for a resolution but have not found one. Please can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance!

```
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\maps_attrs.xml:5: error: Attribute "mapType" has already been defined
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\maps_attrs.xml:12: error: Attribute "cameraBearing" has already been defined
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\maps_attrs.xml:13: error: Attribute "cameraTargetLat" has already been defined
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\maps_attrs.xml:14: error: Attribute "cameraTargetLng" has already been defined
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\maps_attrs.xml:15: error: Attribute "cameraTilt" has already been defined
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\maps_attrs.xml:16: error: Attribute "cameraZoom" has already been defined
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\maps_attrs.xml:17: error: Attribute "uiCompass" has already been defined
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\maps_attrs.xml:18: error: Attribute "uiRotateGestures" has already been defined
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\maps_attrs.xml:19: error: Attribute "uiScrollGestures" has already been defined
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\maps_attrs.xml:20: error: Attribute "uiTiltGestures" has already been defined
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\maps_attrs.xml:21: error: Attribute "uiZoomControls" has already been defined
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\maps_attrs.xml:22: error: Attribute "uiZoomGestures" has already been defined
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\maps_attrs.xml:23: error: Attribute "useViewLifecycle" has already been defined
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\maps_attrs.xml:24: error: Attribute "zOrderOnTop" has already been defined
```

**EDIT**

This is my Android project properties:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have multiple dependencies defining the same things. Please post your `build.gradle` file (if you are using Android Studio) or a screenshot of what is in your Project > Properties > Android dialog (if you are using Eclipse).

Comment: @CommonsWare I have updated my question as you requested

Comment: Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811350/adding-libraries-with-resources-for-android-give-dozen-of-has-already-been-defi#comment38514576_24811350

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the `google-play`services` library twice - and two different versions (one is labeled "froyo" on your screen shot).

Probably delete the old one and it will be fine. But the issue is that you cannot have resources defined twice and differently. Sometimes you can have the some one twice and defined the same and sometimes the build will not detect duplicates in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of one of the two editions of `google-play-services` that you have in your project libraries list.

Comment: Both correct, accepted Jim's because he was one minute faster. To think it was something so stupid, thanks!